# Berkeley Packet Filter struct bpf_insn

Tags: c, packet-capture, sniffing

Can someone explain please how to set a filter using **struct bpf_program** member **struct bpf_insn**? All documentation and tutorials are welcome, for example what would be the struct bpf_insn if i want to filter for example dhcp, dns or ...?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial uses struct bpf_program to create a filter program, not sure if that helps much but it's worth a look. (scroll down to the tcp bit).

http://www.enderunix.org/docs/en/rawipspoof/

Answer (score 0):

See also [the original paper on BPF](http://www.tcpdump.org/papers/bpf-usenix93.pdf), which describes the BPF machine language in section 3.3 "The BPF Pseudo-Machine", and gives some examples of BPF programs in section 3.4 "Examples" and 3.5 "Parsing Packet Headers".